# Jquery - Match a dynamic date string return the amount of matches using length

Tags: javascript, jquery, morris.js

I am building a chart using MorrisJS and so far it`s coming along. I'm having issues with a jquery script at the moment. Im trying to match a date string and have it return the amount of matches found using .lenght. For some reason it always returns 0.

I recreated the problem in the jsfiddle. https://jsfiddle.net/awo5aaqb/2/

This is the code that`s been causing me trouble at the moment:

```
var dates = element.created_date.slice(0,-9);
var count_2015 = $(dates).find('2015'+element.created_date.slice(5,-9)).length;
var count_2016 = $(dates).find('2016'+element.created_date.slice(5,-9)).length;

var obj = { "m": dates, "a": count_2015, "b":count_2016 };
```

What im trying to do is tell jquery to grab my dates (2016-10-01 07:40) I pre slice them to only reutn the year and month (2016-10). I then grab the sliced result and I want to find results that match the year and month and return how many matches it found. It always returns 0. When i run a `console.log(count_2015)` I see that it returns with the result 0 about 40 times.

Would anyone understand why it would do this?

Comment: By doing `element.created_date.slice(5,-9)` are you trying to get `month` or `year`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to use jQuery DOM methods on strings and that won't work

Here's an approach that first loops the data to create an object to count each month in each year

```
var dateCounts = {} 
data.d.results.forEach(function(element) {
      var date = element.created_date.slice(0, 7);
      var yr = date.slice(0, 4);
      if (!dateCounts.hasOwnProperty(yr)) {
        dateCounts[yr] = {}
      }
      if (!dateCounts[yr].hasOwnProperty(date)) {
        dateCounts[yr][date] = 0
      }
      dateCounts[yr][date]++;

});
```

Creates an object like:

```
 {'2015':{'2015-10':3,  ....}, '2016':{'2016-10':9,  ....}}
```

Then to get your chart counts:

Replace:

```
var dates = element.created_date.slice(0,-9);
var count_2015 = $(dates).find('2015'+element.created_date.slice(5,-9)).length;
var count_2016 = $(dates).find('2016'+element.created_date.slice(5,-9)).length;
```

With:

```
  var date = element.created_date.slice(0, 7);
  var yr = date.slice(0, 4);
  var count_2015 = dateCounts['2015'][date];
  var count_2016 = dateCounts['2016'][date];
```

This could probably be streamlined a bit more also

<kbd>**[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/awo5aaqb/4/)**</kbd>